# Is there a way to make bdate_range with 4h and without weekends in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, date-range

I have a data set that shows trades made every 4h over 3 years. I am trying to make a bdate_range that reflects this time interval, but when I use

`days = pd.bdate_range(start='8/4/2014', end='8/3/2017', freq="4H")`

then I get an output that includes weekends. I want to use the bdate_range in a way that it creates a series with each business day 6 times in a row with the corresponding 4h interval like so (without the **middle** section):

```
(DatetimeIndex(['2014-08-04 00:00:00', '2014-08-04 04:00:00',
               '2014-08-04 08:00:00', '2014-08-04 12:00:00',
               '2014-08-04 16:00:00', '2014-08-04 20:00:00',
               '2014-08-05 00:00:00', '2014-08-05 04:00:00',
               '2014-08-05 08:00:00', '2014-08-05 12:00:00',
               '2014-08-05 16:00:00', '2014-08-05 20:00:00',
               '2014-08-06 00:00:00', '2014-08-06 04:00:00',
               '2014-08-06 08:00:00', '2014-08-06 12:00:00',
               '2014-08-06 16:00:00', '2014-08-06 20:00:00',
               '2014-08-07 00:00:00', '2014-08-07 04:00:00',
               '2014-08-07 08:00:00', '2014-08-07 12:00:00',
               '2014-08-07 16:00:00', '2014-08-07 20:00:00',
               '2014-08-08 00:00:00', '2014-08-08 04:00:00',
               '2014-08-08 08:00:00', '2014-08-08 12:00:00',
               '2014-08-08 16:00:00', '2014-08-08 20:00:00',
```

```
               '2014-08-09 00:00:00', '2014-08-09 04:00:00',
               '2014-08-09 08:00:00', '2014-08-09 12:00:00',
               '2014-08-09 16:00:00', '2014-08-09 20:00:00',
               '2014-08-10 00:00:00', '2014-08-10 04:00:00',
               '2014-08-10 08:00:00', '2014-08-10 12:00:00',
               '2014-08-10 16:00:00', '2014-08-10 20:00:00',
```

```
               '2014-08-11 00:00:00', '2014-08-11 04:00:00',
               '2014-08-11 08:00:00', '2014-08-11 12:00:00',
               '2014-08-11 16:00:00', '2014-08-11 20:00:00',
               '2014-08-12 00:00:00', '2014-08-12 04:00:00',
               '2014-08-12 08:00:00', '2014-08-12 12:00:00',
               '2014-08-12 16:00:00', '2014-08-12 20:00:00',
               '2014-08-13 00:00:00', '2014-08-13 04:00:00',
               '2014-08-13 08:00:00', '2014-08-13 12:00:00',
               '2014-08-13 16:00:00', '2014-08-13 20:00:00',
               '2014-08-14 00:00:00']
```

any thoughts on best way to get this result?